# Column bind two RDD in scala spark without KEYs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

The two RDDs have the same number of rows.
I am searching for the R's equivalent to cbind()

It seems join() always requires a key.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest is `.zip` method. With appropriate subsequent `.map` usage. E.g.:

```
val rdd0 = sc.parallelize(Seq( (1, (2,3)), (2, (3,4)) ))
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq( (200,300), (300,400) ))
val zipRdd = (rdd0 zip rdd1).collect
```

returns:

```
zipRdd: Array[((Int, (Int, Int)), (Int, Int))] = Array(((1,(2,3)),(200,300)), ((2,(3,4)),(300,400)))
```

Indeed based on k,v with same num rows required.